# passing NSInpuStream and outputStream between views in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 views both which need a NSInputStream and a NSOutputStream Variable,MY question is how can i get the input stream /outpustream from the first in the second.

The first ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,NSStreamDelegate{
 var inputStream : NSInputStream!
 var outputStrean : NSOutputStream!
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.initNetworkCommunication()

 } 

 func initNetworkCommunication() {
 //here i init the both of them
 }

}
```

Now the second one should use the same things not having to reconnect[doing the same initNetworkCommunication] in the server once again.

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController,NSStreamDelegate {
 var inputStream : NSInputStream!
 var outputStrean : NSOutputStream!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    inputStream = ???
    outputStrean =???
 }
}
```

I tried with getters but for some ereason i get an extra parameter in the function call

Update :
After a closer look I still am facing this issue.because  i use a read and a write stream that I initiate with

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault,"localhost",8023,&readStream,&writeStream)
   inputStream = self.readStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
    outputStrean = self.writeStream!.takeUnretainedValue()
```

After following an advice and initiating the read stream from the one in the first viewController i get  an error that they are null.The issue is that I want to avoid multiple connections  from a single user to the server and at the moment this is the only way it works

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

You can get it by the writing a protocol or otherwise passing the data to ViewController class object.

So lets see how to pass the data to the object.

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

 }

  func getViewController(storyBoard: NSString) -> UIViewController
    {
        var mystoryBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var ViewControllerID : UIViewController = mystoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyBoard) as UIViewController
        return ViewControllerID
    }

func buttonClickedFunction()
{
 var viewController2Object : ViewController2 = getViewController("ViewController2StoryBoardName") as ViewController2
viewController2Object.inputStream = "" // give the value which you want to pass to the ViewController2
viewController2Object.outputStream = ""//  give the value which you want to pass to the ViewController2
  self.presentViewController(viewController2Object, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
}




class ViewController2: UIViewController {

 var inputStream : NSInputStream!
 var outputStrean : NSOutputStream!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     inputStream // use this values in code
    outputStream // use this values in code
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly this  doesn;t work either.look at the code update

Comment: Unfortunatelly this  doesn;t work either.look at the code update cause i think it's a minor issue that i seem to not notice @Alvin Varghese